# The error was:call of non-function ('module' object)

Tags: python, jes

I am stuck using JES for this particular project, and yes, I would rather be poked in the eye. In the mean time, I am stuck with this interesting issue where I cannot load my python package in JES. I was told that this strategy would work. When I give dummy definitions to all the JES functions, and then run the Project in Pycharm, everything works "fine" (given the expected behavior of the dummy functions). I can't figure out what exaclty is going on with JES.

Does anyone have any experience with loading custom python packages in JES?

**Project Structure**

```
Project
  main.py
  MyPackage
     __init__.py
     allmygoodies
```

**Main.py**

```
""" getMediaPath() and setMediaPath() are built in JES functions """ 
import sys
setMediaPath() # Setting it to project root
sys.path.append(getMediaPath()) # Appending Project Root
sys.path.append(getMediaPath() + "MyPackage") # Also tried this
from MyPackage import * # Importing everything from package

myObject = MyObject()
```

**Error**

```
The error was:call of non-function ('module' object)
Inappropriate argument type.
An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, I had to switch to JES 5+. I was previously using JES 4 which does not support this ability.